# Python-requests GET with strings from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

When I try to `GET` a webpage with *requests*, I get the page successfully while the link stored in a str variable. Yet, when I try to get with an element of a str array I can't retrieve the page.

#### Input 1:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

f = open("pages.txt","r")
file = open("parsed.txt","a")
content = f.readlines()

for i in range(1):

    a="http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=2017/2018-3&kisaadi=BM&bolum=BIOMEDICAL+ENGINEERING"
    print(a + " " + str(type(a) ) )

    req_link=a
    r=requests.get(req_link)
    c=r.content

    soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    all=soup.find_all("td")
    print(all[38])
```

#### Output1:

```
PS E:\pythonCodes\BounCP> python .\getClasses.py
http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=2017/2018-3&kisaadi=BM&bolum=BIOMEDICAL+ENGINEERING <class 'str'>
<td><font style="font-size:12px">BM  519.01</font> </td>
```

#### Input 2:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

f = open("pages.txt","r")
file = open("parsed.txt","a")
content = f.readlines()

for i in range(1):

    a=content[1]
    print( content[1] + " "+ str(type(content[1]) ) )

    req_link=a
    r=requests.get(req_link)
    c=r.content

    soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    all=soup.find_all("td")
    #all=all[38:]
    print(all)
```

#### Output2:

```
PS E:\pythonCodes\BounCP> python .\getClasses.py
http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=2017/2018-3&kisaadi=BM&bolum=BIOMEDICAL+ENGINEERING
 <class 'str'>
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a linebreak at the end of your line coming from the file, by seeing the output value before `<class 'str'>`

try with

```
a=content[1].strip()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.